# Use class instance variable to define a button label within the decorator (discord.py 2.0.0)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm attempting to make a small, interchangeable two-button class that I can call in any cog instead of writing out the same code over and over. Everything works fine except for the buttons' labels, which I cannot find out how to assign from the variables. Called as `opt1` or `self.opt1`, it failed since neither are technically "defined" which I do understand, but I can't seem to find any alternatives.

The snippet of the class is as follows:

```py
class twoButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author, opt1="Yes", opt2="No", timeout=0):
        self.author = author
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label=opt1, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="opt1")
    async def buttonOne(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green
            self.buttonTwo.style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
            await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)

    @discord.ui.button(label=opt2, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="opt2")
    async def buttonTwo(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green
            self.buttonOne.style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
            await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return interaction.user.id == self.author.id
```

Is this possible to fix? If so, is there an actual method for getting a variable into a decorator without making a separate class for every use case?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Why not directly use `label="Yes"` in the first case and `label="No"` in the second? I don't understand why there are parameters with values that act like variables in the function. Why do you give the parameters values and then refer to them to use the values as if they're variables when you can replace them directly because they're unique?

Comment: The "Yes" and "No" are intended to be defaults for the pair of buttons, but I'd like to be able to define those two labels when I call the buttons in the first place (per class instance).

Comment: Oh. So, do you mean you'll create the `twoButton`s overriding the default `"Yes"` and `"No"` parameters (`opt1` and `opt2`)?

Comment: That was the plan, but I can't really seem to give the new label titles to the decorator (discord.ui.button) without it erroring.

Comment: But how are you using annotations in a class? Is it allowed in Python? I think you can use [`ActionRow`s](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#action-rows) instead. It's a container for other `View`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation

You can add the buttons dynamically, using `View.add_item`. This can be done in `__init__`, where the definition of the button would have access to the instance attribute.

Important changes:

- The button callback only takes `interaction` as a parameter - you already have access to the button, and the callback is merely a function, not a method (no need for `self`).
- Note the capital 'B' for `Button`. It's a class's constructor, not a decorator.

### Code

```py
class TestView(discord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self, example_var):
        self.example_var = example_var
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.add_buttons()

    def add_buttons(self):
        button_one = discord.ui.Button(label=self.example_var)

        async def button_example(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            print(self.example_var)

        button_one.callback = button_example
        self.add_item(button_one)
```

### Reference

[`discord.ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#view)

[`discord.ui.Button`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#id1)